# Calculat 40 and 60 - he is paid 2.5 times the previous rate for hours worked above 60

Tags: python-3.x

Calculate the pay of an employee given that:
- he is paid 1.5 times the hourly rate for hours worked between 40 and 60
- he is paid 2.5 times the previous rate for hours worked above 60

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. However, it's not DoMyHomeworkOverflow. To get answers you'll need to show some specific code that you are having trouble with. See [ask] and [mcve] for tips on good questions.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply using the conditionals in python. If you know about if-elif :

```
pay=0.0
hourly_rate=25
hours=56
if(40<=hours<=60):
    pay=hourly_rate*40+(hours-40)*hourly_rate*1.5
elif(hours>60):
    pay=hourly_rate*40+20*hourly_rate*1.5+(hours-60)*hourly_rate*2.5
```